# What conditions are necessary on $a,b,c,d$ so that the Möbius transformation $w=\frac{az-b}{cz-d}$ has only one fixed point?

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

**Question:**

> What conditions are necessary on $a,b,c,d$ so that the Möbius transformation $w=\frac{az-b}{cz-d}$ has only one fixed point?

**Attempt:**
We examine
$$ z=\frac{az-b}{cz-d}$$
to find that any fixed point of a Möbius transformation must satisfy
$$cz^2 + (d-a)z - b =0.$$
Hence, there are either one or two fixed points in $\mathbb{R}$ OR two fixed points in $\mathbb{C}$ which are all characterized by
$$z = \frac{(a-d) \pm \sqrt{(d-a)^2+4bc}}{2c}.$$
Hence, there can only be a fixed point when the discriminant $(d-a)^2+4bc$ is zero. Further, if there is only one fixed point, it must be in $\mathbb{R}$.

Can someone with more knowledge than me comment on if my approach is right? Is there a better way to solve this question?

Comment: Why should the fixed point lie in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @DanielFischer The reason I believe it should lie in $\mathbb{R}$ is because $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$. If there is only one fixed point, then (if I'm right) the discriminant is zero and what remains is in $\mathbb{R}$. I think the only way for a complex number to "arise" is if the discriminant < 0. I could be mistaken.

Comment: If you only consider Möbius transformations with real coefficients, you should mention that. That indeed implies that it cannot have a non-real complex fixed point. However, it is possible that the fixed point is $\infty$, consider $z\mapsto z+1$.

Comment: Are you assuming the Möbius transformations normalised so that the determinant is $1$?

Comment: @DanielFischer, on your last question, no. I am only assuming that $ad-bc \neq 0$. I thought the "standard" definition of a Mobius transform implied that $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ -- I guess I'm mistaken on this point. Also, I would be happy to upvote your comments if you were interested in submitting them as an answer (since you are addressing my question directly).

Comment: In complex analysis, we take the coefficients complex. Restricting to real coefficients yields only the automorphisms of the sphere that let $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ invariant, and not yield all automorphisms. The normalisation $\det A = 1$ isn't important, but sometimes it's assumed, so I asked. Anyway, you need to distinguish between "$\infty$ is the sole fixed point" and "the fixed point lies in $\mathbb{C}$". Your computation treats the latter. Look a bit more at the discriminant and try to see how to express it in invariants of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: You've missed the case $c=0$. Then there is a single fixed point when $a\neq 1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you've forgotten the possibility that $c=0$. Then you get a single fixed point when $a\neq d$.

The rest of your answer is correct, but an alternative is to note that $(d-a)^2+4bc = (a+d)^2 -4(ad-bc)$. That's interesting becuase $a+d$ is the trace and $ad-bc$ is the determinant of the matrix:$$A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$$

Note, if you allow $\infty$ in your domain and range, then the case $c=0$ is different, then $a=d$ and $b\neq 0$. This is a stronger answer, because what it means is that the general solution ($c=0$ or $c\neq 0$) is of the form:$$A = U\begin{pmatrix}x&y\\0&x\end{pmatrix}U^{-1}$$ with some invertible matrix $U$, with $xy\neq 0$. That's because the zero value of the discriminant means that the eigenvalues of the matrix must be the same, and the matrix can't be a diagonal matrix or then the transformation is the identity.

This can be stated briefly as: $A$ is not diagonalizable over $\mathbb C$.

Comment: He said nothing about the inclusion of $\infty$, @DanielFischer .

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't meant as an insult. My apologies. I thought you just had mistyped since I am used to considering Möbius transformations as maps $\widehat{\mathbb{C}} \to \widehat{\mathbb{C}}$ by default.

Comment: It's certainly true that the answer becomes different if you consider the point $\infty$ in the domain and range, which is common, but the question seemed naive (in the sense of uninitiated) so I assumed we hadn't gotten to that yet.